# Parsing emails with bad mime types in python

Tags: python, email, mime-types, attachment

I am trying to use python's `imaplib` and `email.feedparser` to grab an attachment out of a gmail inbox. The email is generated by an external party and sent to us, so I have no control over it.

The trouble is that the message I am trying to parse has `msg.get_content_maintype()` return `'text'` instead of `'multitype'`. As a result the uuencoded attachment gets concatenated with the rest of the message and I don't see an ease way to pull it out of `email.message.Message`.

Any ideas how I can extract the attachment out of such an email?

If it is any help, the email has 'Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V6.00.3790.4862' in it. Thunderbird also had trouble rendering this email and wasn't able to figure out that it had an attachment. Otherwise, the message looks ok in Outlook and Gmail web client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [email.parser.FeedParser documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/email.parser.html#email.parser.FeedParser) says you can use `_factory` parameter to provide your own `Message` class. You could put your own class derived from `email.message.Message` that will replace message contenttype with the correct one if this message was composed in "Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE ...blablabla".

I think it is safe to expect that the messagesin this particular case will always be multipart.

Comment: Thanks. This may be the canonical way of solving this. Last night I figured out a hackish way of doing by decoding `_payload` on the message with `uu`. Will post that as an answer in a little bit.

Comment: @Roger I will highly appreciate if you accept my solution here as it is canonical way;)